# How to create a procedure to remove all special characters and duplicate records

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a procedure to remove all special characters from a column of my spesific table and then remove duplicate records.

I tried the following query so far to show the desired logic :

```
SELECT  ft_nm_val,count(*)  
  FROM ( SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ft_nm_val, '[^A-Za-z0-9, ]') AS ft_nm_val 
           FROM fraud_token_name )
 GROUP BY ft_nm_val  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: maybe you could provide more context to get good answers:
for example:  
`The string <string> should be transformed to <new_string>`

also you could explain what you intended wit the code you posted.

Comment: How is your current approch failing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove duplicate records and if there are other columns exist in the table, then concept ***duplicate*** would change row-wisely. So, I assume you have that table with only one column mentioned. Then you can create such a procedure :

```
SQL> create or replace procedure make_unique is
begin
--# Leave only alpha-numeric characters through applying [^  ] to [:alnum:] posix
  update fraud_token_name
     set ft_nm_val = regexp_replace(ft_nm_val,'[^[:alnum:]]');

--# Then delete duplicate records
  delete fraud_token_name f1
   where rowid <
                (
                select max(rowid)
                  from fraud_token_name f2
                 where f2.ft_nm_val = f1.ft_nm_val   
                );  
  commit;
end;
/

SQL> exec make_unique;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0ef071ae09cc1dadb1bc04a90f75690b)</kbd>